# "our bodies lose their rhythm" vs. "our body loses its rhythm"

Tags: meaning, differences, grammatical-number

[image: snippet from question paper]

In this above situation, the question is that **“What happens if we change our sleep pattern often?”** and my brother had to fill in the blanks.

> A: ______ ______ ______ ______ ______ .

So he answered, “Our bodies lose their rhythm.”.

But his teacher said the answer was wrong. The correct answer which she wants is

> “Our body loses its rhythm.”

My brother’s answer is wrong?
I would like to know if this answer is incorrect or not and if not, what is the difference in meaning between them.

Answer (score 1):

Your brother's got a strong case: the teacher changed the pronoun to 'we' so your brother correspondingly pluralised his answer, rather than simply using a verbatim quote. The sense of it remains the same.